Is there some kind of API to turn on Media HTTP Basic Auth?
https://help.twilio.com/articles/15827821586843-Prevent-unauthorized-access-to-your-Programmable-Voice-Media-with-HTTP-Basic-Auth

In our application, we have a lot of sub accounts which we want to turn on HTTP Basic Auth for. Doing this by hand would take a lot of times and we might miss some.
So I want to ask if there is some kind of API that we can use to turn this on, cause I can't seem to find it

This option can be configured just by Console, so it doesn't have an API to change it.
